# Suppress default login

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, login

I want to run a Ubuntu 16.04 server in a VirtualBox VM in a Windows 10 host without a prompt for login, without an automatic login  and preferably without the VirtualBox supplied console. I want all maintenance interaction with the machine to be via ssh. I have been unable to find anything that explains how to do this and any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean, you want to just power on the ubuntu server virtual machine and want to access it via ssh from host (windows) ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like.

Comment: How to start a VBox machine headless: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just power on the virtual machine and keep it on.

Download and install the [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) in Windows to ssh into virtual machine.